# GooglePlay Purchase Receipt Validation Doubts

Tags: google-api-java-client, google-play-developer-api

We see some of the GooglePlay purchase receipts fail to validate. And the response we receive from GooglePlay API is

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
    {
      "code" : 400,
      "errors" : [ {
        "domain" : "global",
        "message" : "Invalid Value",
        "reason" : "invalid"
      } ],
      "message" : "Invalid Value"
    }
```

It is a very generic response and i can't tell much from it. Things i am wondering about -

1. Is there a particular format of a valid purchase receipt ? I see 2 kinds of purchase receipts in our logs -

> Type 1 -> ljcunhtiyblsklqvpigvxxxx
>
> Type 2 ->
>   lmomhgjkfhhnegclffaimede.AO-J1OxxXX_ra8GXkDMVsa96mX6FDdIMMdA6OIGAaMirvWmt53NFTJOTSw_yy66ytxME-mtEqwj3afEgsLo0_mFd_-8raZslmzmCNzoVNEfQ1fbT4k8iMppYdPtwZ_i0GI8WA51f3PlPWJS9UC5H_jgBaR_25xxxxx

Type 2 receipts don't fail to validate. Only Type 1 receipts fail. Any thoughts ?

We have both consumable and non-consumable products in our app. No subscription purchases.

Comment: I have the same problem, have you solved this? Why the first receipt is so short?